# The possible reason for opencv cannot find .png format images

Tags: opencv

I just find my `opencv` cannot find `.png` format images, but works fine with loading other format like `.jpg` images. I built `opencv4.01` with vs2015. Here below are the CMake configurations I saved when the opencv was built:

```
-- Selecting Windows SDK version  to target Windows 10.0.17763.
  -- AVX_512F is not supported by C++ compiler
  -- AVX512_SKX is not supported by C++ compiler
  -- Dispatch optimization AVX512_SKX is not available, skipped
  -- libjpeg-turbo: VERSION = 1.5.3, BUILD = opencv-4.0.1-libjpeg-turbo
  -- Looking for Mfapi.h
  -- Looking for Mfapi.h - found
  -- found Intel IPP (ICV version): 2019.0.0 [2019.0.0 Gold]
  -- at: C:/opencv-4.0/cmake-build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/icv
  -- found Intel IPP Integration Wrappers sources: 2019.0.0
  -- at: C:/opencv-4.0/cmake-build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/iw
  -- CUDA detected: 9.0
  -- CUDA NVCC target flags: -gencode;arch=compute_30,code=sm_30;-gencode;arch=compute_35,code=sm_35;-gencode;arch=compute_37,code=sm_37;-gencode;arch=compute_50,code=sm_50;-gencode;arch=compute_52,code=sm_52;-gencode;arch=compute_60,code=sm_60;-gencode;arch=compute_61,code=sm_61;-gencode;arch=compute_70,code=sm_70;-D_FORCE_INLINES
  -- Could not find OpenBLAS include. Turning OpenBLAS_FOUND off
  -- Could not find OpenBLAS lib. Turning OpenBLAS_FOUND off
  -- Could NOT find BLAS (missing: BLAS_LIBRARIES)
  -- LAPACK requires BLAS
  -- A library with LAPACK API not found. Please specify library location.
  -- VTK is not found. Please set -DVTK_DIR in CMake to VTK build directory, or to VTK install subdirectory with VTKConfig.cmake file
  -- OpenCV Python: during development append to PYTHONPATH: C:/opencv-4.0/cmake-build/python_loader

  -- Module opencv_cudaoptflow disabled because opencv_optflow dependency can't be resolved!
  -- Module opencv_superres disabled because opencv_optflow dependency can't be resolved!

  -- Excluding from source files list: <BUILD>/modules/dnn/layers/layers_common.avx512_skx.cpp
  --
  -- General configuration for OpenCV 4.0.1 =====================================
  --   Version control:               unknown
  --
  --   Extra modules:
  --     Location (extra):            D:/Software/Programming/OpenCV/opencv_contrib-4.0.1/modules
  --     Version control (extra):     unknown
  --
  --   Platform:
  --     Timestamp:                   2019-03-23T15:52:48Z
  --     Host:                        Windows 10.0.17763 AMD64
  --     CMake:                       3.13.4
  --     CMake generator:             Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64
  --     CMake build tool:            C:/Program Files (x86)/MSBuild/14.0/bin/MSBuild.exe
  --     MSVC:                        1900
  --
  --   CPU/HW features:
  --     Baseline:                    SSE SSE2 SSE3
  --       requested:                 SSE3
  --     Dispatched code generation:  SSE4_1 SSE4_2 FP16 AVX AVX2
  --       requested:                 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 AVX FP16 AVX2 AVX512_SKX
  --       SSE4_1 (7 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1
  --       SSE4_2 (2 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2
  --       FP16 (1 files):            + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 AVX
  --       AVX (5 files):             + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 AVX
  --       AVX2 (13 files):           + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2
  --
  --   C/C++:
  --     Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
  --     C++ Compiler:                C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe  (ver 19.0.24215.1)
  --     C++ flags (Release):         /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi      /EHa /wd4127 /wd4251 /wd4324 /wd4275 /wd4512 /wd4589 /MP4   /MD /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG
  --     C++ flags (Debug):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi      /EHa /wd4127 /wd4251 /wd4324 /wd4275 /wd4512 /wd4589 /MP4   /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1
  --     C Compiler:                  C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe
  --     C flags (Release):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi        /MP4    /MD /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG
  --     C flags (Debug):             /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi        /MP4  /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1
  --     Linker flags (Release):      /machine:x64  /INCREMENTAL:NO
  --     Linker flags (Debug):        /machine:x64  /debug /INCREMENTAL
  --     ccache:                      NO
  --     Precompiled headers:         YES
  --     Extra dependencies:          cudart.lib nppc.lib nppial.lib nppicc.lib nppicom.lib nppidei.lib nppif.lib nppig.lib nppim.lib nppist.lib nppisu.lib nppitc.lib npps.lib cublas.lib cufft.lib -LIBPATH:C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v9.0/lib/x64
  --     3rdparty dependencies:
  --
  --   OpenCV modules:
  --     To be built:                 bioinspired calib3d core cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudastereo cudawarping cudev dnn dnn_objdetect features2d flann gapi highgui imgcodecs imgproc java_bindings_generator ml objdetect phase_unwrapping photo plot python_bindings_generator reg saliency shape stereo stitching structured_light surface_matching tracking ts video videoio xfeatures2d ximgproc xobjdetect xphoto
  --     Disabled:                    world
  --     Disabled by dependency:      cudaoptflow superres
  --     Unavailable:                 java js python2 python3
  --     Applications:                tests apps
  --     Documentation:               NO
  --     Non-free algorithms:         NO
  --
  --   Windows RT support:            NO
  --
  --   GUI:
  --     Win32 UI:                    YES
  --     VTK support:                 NO
  --
  --   Media I/O:
  --     ZLib:                        build (ver 1.2.11)
  --     JPEG:                        build-libjpeg-turbo (ver 1.5.3-62)
  --     WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020e)
  --     TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.0.9)
  --     JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 1.900.1)
  --     OpenEXR:                     build (ver 1.7.1)
  --     HDR:                         YES
  --     SUNRASTER:                   YES
  --     PXM:                         YES
  --     PFM:                         YES
  --
  --   Video I/O:
  --     DC1394:                      NO
  --     FFMPEG:                      YES (prebuilt binaries)
  --       avcodec:                   YES (ver 58.35.100)
  --       avformat:                  YES (ver 58.20.100)
  --       avutil:                    YES (ver 56.22.100)
  --       swscale:                   YES (ver 5.3.100)
  --       avresample:                YES (ver 4.0.0)
  --     GStreamer:                   NO
  --     DirectShow:                  YES
  --     Media Foundation:            YES
  --       DXVA:                      NO
  --
  --   Parallel framework:            Concurrency
  --
  --   Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)
  --
  --   Other third-party libraries:
  --     Intel IPP:                   2019.0.0 Gold [2019.0.0]
  --            at:                   C:/opencv-4.0/cmake-build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/icv
  --     Intel IPP IW:                sources (2019.0.0)
  --               at:                C:/opencv-4.0/cmake-build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/iw
  --     Lapack:                      NO
  --     Eigen:                       NO
  --     Custom HAL:                  NO
  --     Protobuf:                    build (3.5.1)
  --
  --   NVIDIA CUDA:                   YES (ver 9.0, CUFFT CUBLAS NVCUVID)
  --     NVIDIA GPU arch:             30 35 37 50 52 60 61 70
  --     NVIDIA PTX archs:
  --
  --   OpenCL:                        YES (no extra features)
  --     Include path:                D:/Software/Programming/opencv-4.0.1/opencv-4.0.1/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
  --     Link libraries:              Dynamic load
  --
  --   Python (for build):            C:/Python36/python.exe
  --
  --   Java:
  --     ant:                         NO
  --     JNI:                         C:/Java/include C:/Java/include/win32 C:/Java/include
  --     Java wrappers:               NO
  --     Java tests:                  NO
  --
  --   Install to:                    C:/opencv-4.0/mybuild
  -- -----------------------------------------------------------------
  --
  -- Configuring done
  -- Generating done
```

I wonder if there are any modules I missed for loading `.png` images, or other reasons for that failure.

Comment: I don't use Windows, but I would have expected to find PNG listed under `Media I/O` near JPEG. Curious that you have `Zlib` which normally goes hand-in-hand with PNG. My guess is that you need to install/re-install `libpng`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell On windows, you shouldn't need to install anything -- the source code of OpenCV already ships with the code of a lot of 3rd party libraries (including libpng). It should also build libpng [by default on WIN32](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.0.1/CMakeLists.txt#L213) and [include the support](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.0.1/CMakeLists.txt#L302)... odd.

Comment: OP, How exactly did you configure it? Provide all the commands to reproduce this.